Let $X$ be a metric space, $S, A \subset X$. Prove that $S$ is dense in $A$ if and only if $A\subset \overline{S}$ .
My attempt:
($\Leftarrow$)
Let $x_0\in A$. By hypothesis $A\subset \overline{S}$, and from definition of $\overline{S}$, we have $x_0\in S\cup S'$.
Case 1. If $x_0\in S$, then $\forall \epsilon > 0$
\begin{equation}
  B_{\epsilon}(x_0)\cap S\neq \emptyset,
\end{equation}
and by definition $S$ is dense in $A$.
Case 2. If $x_0\in S'$, then $x_0$ is the accumulation point of $S$,
which implies that $\forall \epsilon > 0$
\begin{equation}
       B_{\epsilon}(x_0)\cap S\setminus \{x_0\}\neq \emptyset.
\end{equation}
On the other hand we have,
\begin{equation}
       B_{\epsilon}(x_0)\cap S\setminus \{x_0\}\subset B_{\epsilon}(x_0)\cap S
\quad \Rightarrow \quad B_{\epsilon}(x_0)\cap S\neq \emptyset
\end{equation}
and again by definition $S$ is dense in $A$. In both cases
we have that $S$ is dense in $A$.
($\Rightarrow$)
Let be $x_0\in A$. We have that $S$ is dense in $A$ which implies
$\forall$ $\epsilon>0$
\begin{equation}
            B_{\epsilon}(x_0)\cap S \neq \emptyset,
\end{equation}
but
\begin{equation}
            B_{\epsilon}(x_0)\cap S \subset 
  A \cap S 
\end{equation}
which implies
\begin{equation}
  A \cap S \neq \emptyset.
\end{equation}
Then $x_0\in A\cap S$ or $x_0\notin A\cap S$ that is to say
$x_0\in S$ or $x_0\notin A\cap S$
But, i don't know how to conclude that $x_0$ is the accumulation point of $S$...
If you can help me by checking that the first part is correct and an idea for the second part, I would appreciate it.

I have a question on the first part (<=).  How do you know that $x_{0}$ is an accumulation point of $S?$  If I understand the meaning of $A \subset \overline{S}$, all you can say is $x_{0}$ is in the closure of $S$, but may not necessarily be an accumulation point.  I am assuming that $\overline{S}=S' \cup S$, where $S'$ is the set of accumulation points of $S.$  Maybe your definition is different. Perhaps this is useful.  Thanks.

You're right. In effect, $S'$ is the set of accumulation points of $S$. Based on your comment, I added the other case that was wrong in the first part, although I had not included it because it was obvious to me, but it could be that I am wrong, I would appreciate it if you would review it again. Greetings

So, for example, the rationals $S$ is dense in the irrationals $A$ because $A \subseteq \overline{S}$ ??  Is that wheat you mean?

Following up on the comments, here are a few considerations that might be useful.
Regarding $\impliedby$ part of proof:
I believe that Case 1 and Case 2 together imply $S$ is dense in $A$ (but not separately).  This is because for every $x_{0} \in A$, you have shown that $B_{\epsilon}\left(x_{0}\right) \cap S \ne \emptyset,$ no matter if $x_{0} \in S$ or $x_{0} \in S'.$  (Please note that I am assuming that $B_{\epsilon}\left(x_{0}\right)$ represents the "neighborhood" of $x_{0}$ of radius $\epsilon).$
Also, I'm not sure if you need to specify $\setminus \{x_{0}\}$ in Case 2.
Regarding $\implies$ part of proof:
Suppose $x_{0} \notin \left[ B_{\epsilon}\left(x_{0}\right) \cap S \right ]  \forall \epsilon.$  This implies $x_{0}$ must be an accumulation point of $S$, so $x_{0} \in S'$.  This is by definition of accumulation point.
Now, suppose $x_{0} \in \left [ B_{\epsilon}\left(x_{0}\right) \cap S\right]$ for at least one $\epsilon.$  Then, $x_{0} \in S$, because $x_{0}$ is in the intersection.
Thus, it has been shown that $x_{0} \in S$ or $x_{0} \in S' \implies A \subset \overline{S}$.
Hopefully this makes sense.

thank you so much. With your comment and making graphs I understood more
